# Evaluating conditional expression

Tags: lambda-calculus

I want to show that

$$
(\lambda fgx. fx(gx)) (\lambda xy. x) (\lambda xy.x) = \lambda x. x
$$

Here's my try:

$$
(\lambda fgx. fx(gx)) (\lambda xy. x) (\lambda xy.x)
= (\lambda fgx. fx(gx)) \underline{true} \ \underline{true}
= \lambda x. \underline{true} \ x (\underline{true} \ x)
= \lambda x. (\underline{true} \rightarrow x \ | \ \underline{true} \ x)
= \lambda x. x
$$

$\square$

Are the steps correct and reasonable? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I don't understand the notation $\lambda x. (\underline{true} \rightarrow x \ | \ \underline{true} \ x)$. What does it stand for?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco it means if true then x else (true x) which evaluates to x here.